# How can i create a stable checksum of a media file?

Tags: ffmpeg, media, sha1, checksum, mplayer

how can i create a checksum of only the media data without the metadata to get a stable identification for a media file. preferably an cross platform approach with a library that has support for many formats. e.g. vlc, ffmpeg or mplayer.

(media files should be audio and video in common formats, images would be nice to have too)

Comment: I think you are looking for some fingerprinting algorithm... Which would be interesting as it can be used to identify similar media, too. Looking forward to answers, bumping. +1

Comment: fingerprinting is interesting too, there is e.g. libofa [1] for audio (which i could not compile on osx despite patches) but i want something more generic to identify duplicate files and not duplicate songs/movies. 

[1] http://code.google.com/p/musicip-libofa/

Comment: by "without the tags" do you mean "without the metadata"? if so, saying "media data" may confuse things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shell script around mvik's ffmpeg-based [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68577633/18227053) which prints the MD5 in case of success, or the stderr output in case of failure.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Compute the MD5 of the audio stream of an MP3 file, ignoring ID3 tags.

# The problem with comparing MP3 files is that a simple change to the ID3 tags
# in one file will cause the two files to have differing MD5 sums.  This script
# avoids that problem by taking the MD5 of only the audio stream, ignoring the
# tags.

# Note that by virtue of using ffmpeg, this script happens to also work for any
# other audio file format supported by ffmpeg (not just MP3's).

set -e

stdoutf=$( mktemp mp3md5.XXXXXX )
stderrf=$( mktemp mp3md5.XXXXXX )

set +e
ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:a copy -f md5 - >$stdoutf 2>$stderrf
ret=$?
set -e

if test $ret -ne 0 ; then
    cat $stderrf
else
    cat $stdoutf | sed 's/MD5=//'
fi

rm -f $stdoutf $stderrf
exit $ret
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, it may be 11 years too late for an answer, but in case others like me stumble upon this...

`ffmpeg` can output checksums for individual streams. So the same audio or video would output the same checksum independently of it's container format or metadata.

Example for the video track of file `$filename`, writing the output to `$filename.md5` :

```
ffmpeg -i "$filename" -map 0:v -codec copy -f md5 "$filename.md5"
```

For audio, use `-map 0:a`.

To output to STDOUT, use `-`. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i "$filename" -map 0:a -codec copy -hide_banner -loglevel warning -f md5 -
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any existing platform-independent software that will accomplish this, but I do know a way that this could be accomplished in an interpreted (platform-independent) language such as Java.

Essentially, we simply need to strip any metadata (tags) from the file, demultiplexing video files beforehand. Theoretically after demux and removing metadata, one could hash the file and compare against another file that has undergone the same process to match identical files despite having different tags. Unlike a fingerprint, this would not identify similar songs/movies but identical files (imagine you might want the 10 different versions or bitrates of a given song you've archived, but don't want 2 identical copies of any of them floating around).

The most troubling part of this is removing tags as there are many different specifications for tag formats which are not necessarily implemented the same across different applications, i.e. the same exact audio file given identical tags separately through two different applications may not result in identical output files. The only way this could pose an issue fatal to the concept of an audio-only checksum is if popular tagging software makes any changes to the binary audio portion of the file, or pads the audio in a non-standard way.

Taking a checksum is trivial, but I'm not aware off the top of my head of any platform independent libraries to demux and detag mpeg files. I know that in 'nix environments, mpgtx is a great command-line tool that could perform the demux and detag, but obviously that is not a platform-independent solution.

Maybe someone out there feels ambitious?

Comment: this is the way to go.
in the meantime i wrote ha patch for ffmpeg to calculate sha1 hashes instead of adler32 checksum. this essentially does the trick. 
if anyone would like to help me bringing this to ffmpeg that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution i found seems to be with vlc:

```
./VLC -I rc snd.mp3 :sout='#std{mux=raw,access=file,dst=-}' vlc://quit | sha1sum
```

Comment: seems to not work for movies, seems to not be platform independent